# android action dial several numbers

Tags: android, android-intent, action, phone-call

I need to call dial activity and set several phone numbers.Then choose one of them and call it.My code is

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

but it call ony one number. Is it possible to do what i want?Thanks.

Comment: how many phone numbers ur are going to list for user while calling?

Comment: it should not matter.there may be two, and maybe 20

Comment: use this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_list_view.htm. use array  to set the phone no in list view and write the code to call the no which the user need to call from the list view.

Comment: i need to set `uri` to `intent.setData`. How can i get it from array?